# How can I count the number of search result using java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using selenium java
and want to count the result for google search in java
for example i searched for selenium i want to count all these result (not tagname =a )
from the first page then move to page 2 and also count results and assert that they are equal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiBva.png)

expect code for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

String result =
driver.findElement(By.id("s-result-count")).getText().split(" ")[2]; System.out.println(result);

Comment: can you explain more please id value !! and split value what it should be ?

Comment: this code snippet finds an element with the ID “s-result-count,” retrieves its visible text, splits the text by spaces, and prints the third word (index 2) to the console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count amount of search results, you can get elements array, filter by visibility and count their size.

Like

```js
By searchResultLocator = new By.ByCssSelector("a h3");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(searchResultLocator);
int searchResult = (int) elements.stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).count();
driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("[role=navigation] #pnnext")).click();
int secondSearchResults = (int) driver.findElements(searchResultLocator).stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).count();
Assert.assertEquals(searchResult, secondSearchResults);
```